# How to delete random text in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

How to delete random text in Notepad++?
Random text like

```
fTmgxemoyTkFCZzg
fOFo3YklCSTVZSm8
fV1BCN2N5QVRKbVE
fOHhaUFdmU3Bqelk
```

I have almost 400 entries like that.

Comment: This is off topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

if they always start with a "f" and have always the same size and always finish by a new line without any space maybe you could make a regular expression to do a search and replace all. I do not know enough regular expression, but i am sure someone else can give you the apropriate one. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

There are other programs which are better suited for this kind of problem.  In [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), for example, you could type

```
:g/fTmgxemoyTkFCZzg fOFo3YklCSTVZSm8 fV1BCN2N5QVRKbVE fOHhaUFdmU3Bqelk/d
```

to delete any line containing that text.  In [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), you could type

```
M-x flush-lines
fTmgxemoyTkFCZzg fOFo3YklCSTVZSm8 fV1BCN2N5QVRKbVE fOHhaUFdmU3Bqelk
```

where `M-x` is the key combination Alt+X.

Comment: I don't think the random text is always the same. He meant that there are 400 entries which look random.

Comment: Oh.  Then it's the same, with the characters replaced with dots, in both programs.  See [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).